# Dynamically access prisma model

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

We have many different games and while I could write a function that uses a bunch of if statements to get the proper model I would like to solve it  bit cleaner.

I currently have the following code:

```
const { game, id } = request.params as { game: string; id: string }

      const gameMap = {
        'd3' : prisma.d3Profile
      }

      if (!Object.keys(gameMap).includes(game)) {
        return { error: 'unknown game' }
      }
      // @ts-ignore
      const profile = gameMap[game].findUnique({
        where: {
          id: parseInt(id)
        }
      })

      if (profile) {
        return profile
      }
      return { error: 'profile not found'}
```

Everything works but I would love to solve this problem without resorting to using ts-ignore. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly define type of request.params

```
const gameMap = {
  'd3' : prisma.d3Profile
}
const { game, id } = request.params as { game: keyof typeof gameMap; id: string }
```

This way typescript has a way to infer it correctly